# Python Beautiful Soup Extracting HTML Meta Data

Tags: python, html, twitter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am getting some odd behavior that I do not quite understand. I am hoping someone can explain what is going on.

Consider this metadata:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the Tesla Semi truck">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="This is the Tesla Semi truck">
```

This line successfully finds ALL "og" properties and returns a list.

```
opengraphs = doc.html.head.findAll(property=re.compile(r'^og'))
```

However, this line fails to do the same thing for the twitter cards.

```
twitterCards = doc.html.head.findAll(name=re.compile(r'^twitter'))
```

Why does the first line successfully find all the "og" (opengraph cards), but fail to find the twitter cards?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is `name=` which has special meaning. It is used to find tag name - in your code it is `meta`

You have to add `"meta"` and use dictionary with `"name"`

Example with different items.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data='''
<meta property="og:title" content="This is the Tesla Semi truck">
<meta property="twitter:title" content="This is the Tesla Semi truck">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="This is the Tesla Semi truck">
'''

head = BeautifulSoup(data)

print(head.findAll(property=re.compile(r'^og'))) # OK
print(head.findAll(property=re.compile(r'^tw'))) # OK

print(head.findAll(name=re.compile(r'^meta'))) # OK
print(head.findAll(name=re.compile(r'^tw')))   # empty

print(head.findAll('meta', {'name': re.compile(r'^tw')})) # OK
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because `name` is the *name of the tag name argument* which basically means that in this case `BeautifulSoup` would look for elements with tag names that start with `twitter`.

In order to specify that you actually mean an attribute, use:

```
doc.html.head.find_all(attrs={'name': re.compile(r'^twitter')})
```

Or, via a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
doc.html.head.select("[name^=twitter]")
```

where `^=` means "starts with".

Comment: Thank you! If I could accept both answers I would have!!